# How to decrypt Shelter/work profile without access to the app and no credentials?

Tags: twrp, boot-loop, lineageos, micro-g

I am referring to the topic [How to decrypt Island / Work profile and Parallel Apps user in TWRP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231415/how-to-decrypt-island-work-profile-and-parallel-apps-user-in-twrp)

After installing a work profile (via Shelter) I wanted to install a backup of my LineageOS 17.1 via TWRP. My backup did not work and resulted in a bootloop straight into TWRP again:  failed to decrypt user 10.
My problem is: I do not know the user 10 password and I cannot start Android again. I cannot put in the password in TWRP or access the settings like advised in the answer of firelord… stupid me.

Does anybody have a suggestion? Is there a way to wipe the user 10? Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before restoring Lineage backup, did you make backup of the than state of the device? If yes, you might be able to restore it successfully and then follow my answer.

Comment: I did take a backup of the than working LOS (I am using the microG fork, as far as I know it does not have any influence there). After the last OTA update phone calls and sync were an issue, so I wanted to restore the TWRP backup, no success. I even got rid of some data to free the space on the phone (thought it might be the reason), but the restoring process got stuck at the same percentage again. That is when I restored a completely new nightly, same issues as mentioned above. I flashed the newest TWRP (3.5...), interestingly the MIUI 12.1 is starting (flashed it to get the current vendor).

Comment: It was possible to get rid of the encrypted work profile/user 10 with the MiFlashTool. It wiped out everything. But thanks a lot to Firelord for his first response!