# Do I need any sorta CLI parameter, in order to TWRP backup all users?

Tags: backup, twrp

I don't even know if that's a thing, but I decided to ask anyway.

I'm making backups using this line:

```
adb backup -f full.twrp.ab --twrp compress system data
```

Although, I'm not sure if this is making a backup of all android users or just the phone owner.

Comment: You can get all command-line options by executing the backup binary `bu` on the device: `adb shell bu --help`

Comment: One way (which I would have gone with if I had his problem)  to find out is to actually make backup and then extract or peek into it if other users are indeed backed up or not. Make sure to decrypt all users before taking backup.

Comment: @Firelord nice tip! would you mind telling me what is the best way to decrypt my backup on a linux machine? softwares and stuff...

Comment: backup is not encrypted, only compressed. i recommend not to backup multiple partitions in one single file, only create one file per partition https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decrypt Island / Work profile and Parallel Apps user in TWRP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231415/how-to-decrypt-island-work-profile-and-parallel-apps-user-in-twrp)

Comment: for unpacking try this script from post [#7](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-twrp-android-system-recovery-3e-universal-checksum-disabler.3899918/post-81905363)