# TWRP Backup of encrypted files or decrypted ones?

Tags: backup, twrp

I'm using [File Based Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based) on data partition and I want to backup it with TWRP. In this kind of encryption, there are two possibilities to backup files. First, one does not decrypt files in TWRP and take backup files as they are, backup of encrypted files. The second solution is to backup decrypted files, so I need to decrypt files with PIN code in TWRP and then take backup.

Which solution is better and has fewer cons while restoring a backup?

Comment: Always better to go for backup without encryption, in my experience. Reasons 1. TWRP version may not be updated with latest OS version as I saw on One Plus 7 2. Changing ROMs 3. If you need to factory reset or wipe your device, encrypted backup not possible to be restored (even if you use same PIN) 4. [cases like this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231449)

Comment: encrypted backup is useless when keystore in TEE is wiped

Comment: @beeshyams thx for reply. When changing ROM it's better to start with new /data filesystem, it's obvious. To deal with cannot unlock device after restoring TWRP backup is easy, just delete unlock screen config file/sqlite db.

Comment: @alecxs Does TEE still flush keys if /data partition is wiped from TWRP instead of factory reset?

Comment: @defalt from what we both discovered recently that's the point i still don't know. guess not because that requires [deleteKey](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/117414/2020/12/23) command send to TEE